# Prevent default link behaviour when click somewhere in <a> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say we have a like this structure:

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

```html
<a href="page2.html" class="container">
  <div class="preventGoToLinkWhenClick">
    button for open video modal
  </div>
</a>
```

When I click on the div inside, it should not go to the link. Is this possible? I have tried `stopImmediatePropagation()` but does not works.

But should work `<a>` element when click outside the div

Comment: [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) .

Comment: Please describe "does not work". What actually happened and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an event listener to prevent default action if the clicked element contains class `preventGoToLinkWhenClick` (or any criterium you define), otherwise just return

```js
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("preventGoToLinkWhenClick")) {
   evt.preventDefault();
  }
  return;
});
```

```html
<a href=//www.google.com" class="container">
  <div class="preventGoToLinkWhenClick">
    button for open video modal
  </div>
  [click to open]
</a>
```